# Firebase Crash Reporting: Failed to transmit crash: Error 400

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Has anyone tried the new Firebase Crash reporting?

I am stuck with following error after creating a crash

```
Firebase Crash Reporting: Failed to transmit crash: Error Domain=com.google.FirebaseCrash Code=1 "Upload failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Upload failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=HTTP Error Code 400: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x14042c580> { URL: https://mobilecrashreporting.googleapis.com/v1/crashes:batchCreate?key=AIzaSyDASjryPZ%2DxEbhyE9hu09Fw7dhWs4Wj61c&alt=json } { status code: 400, headers {
"Cache-Control" = private;
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 136;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Thu, 01 Sep 2016 09:08:42 GMT";
Server = ESF;
Vary = "Origin, X-Origin, Referer";
"alt-svc" = "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"36,35,34,33,32,31,30\"";
"alternate-protocol" = "443:quic";
"x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
"x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
"x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";} }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue and couldn't figure out what the reason for the 400 error was. Here is a not-too-painful way to get the reason for the error:

Install [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) (or whatever your favorite way to inspect requests is) , go to Help>SSL Proxying>Install Charles Root Certificate in iOS Simulators. Then get it to fail to send the crash report again in the simulator and look for the request to mobilecrashreporting.googleapis.com in Charles. Click on Response to view the actual response JSON, which should have the reason the request is failing.

Mine was an invalid BundleVersion value, yours will probably be something else:

`{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid iOS internal version: '1A001'.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}`

Once I fixed the version number crash reporting started working. This info should really be in the original failure log, so I'm going to make a feature request for that. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue yesterday, after connecting with firebase support I got this reply.

"The possible root cause of this error is the missing API key in your app. This is a known bug which was recently fixed in the Firebase console. Check if you have the API_KEY parameter or property in your GoogleService-Info.plist file.

To resolve this, you can just download a new GoogleService-Info.plist file in the Firebase console by clicking the gear icon in the upper left portion of the screen, and choose project settings."

as it turns out my GoogleService-Info.plist file **was** missing the API_KEY parameter. I downloaded the new file again and all works like a charm.